# Differentiating between two methods with same name but different parameter list when passing null value

Tags: java

I have two methods in the same class with fallowing signatures:

```
public class Clazz{
   public void foo(String);
   public void foo(List<String>);
}
```

When calling methods of this function:

```
Clazz clazz = new Clazz();
clazz.foo(null);
```

`Clazz::foo` is obviously ambiguous because both foo methods can have `null` as arguments. 
Is there a way to differentiate between this two? Btw, I need them both to have the same name.

Comment: Explicitly cast: `clazz.foo((String) null)`

Comment: That was very fast, thank yo so much, post an answer if you want!

Comment: Good question from interview perspective as well ! :) and a quick answer